# Swift Code Error : CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, cgrect

[image]

```
let fdesc : CMFormatDescriptionRef = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)!

let clap  : CGRect =  CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture(fdesc, false)


Error: cannot invoke 'CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture' with an argument list of type '(CMFormatDescriptionRef, Bool)'
```

Comment: That code compiles without problems in my Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try `let fdesc: CMFormatDescription = …`

Comment: In Swift, CMFormatDescriptionRef is a type alias for CMFormatDescription, so I doubt that this will make any difference. Did *you* try it?